# Upload binary button missing on iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, upload, binary

I have an issue where I don't see the button for uploading a binary.
[image]

I tried to google my problem, but nothing of this sort comes out.
Is it maybe that I need some special privilege to upload a binary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no button for upload, the status "`Waiting for upload`" means you need to upload it from XCode or application loader.

Comment: oooh, so that's the case..
Ok then, it changes everything :)
Because i've been watching some tutorial on iTunes Connect, ant there IS an upload button there...

Comment: @Stebra it might be an old video, this means you just need to upload it.